# Selenium Automation retry failed tests using TESTNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can someone please suggest me how to prepare test scripts for batch test execution using testng... I have around 1000 testcases with different test data iteration...

Also I want to execute failed test cases after complete execution of test suite. Suppose there were 1000 test cases and 200 failed then I want to run that 200 again

Answer (score 6):

You could simply rerun the tests by calling testng-failed.xml
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning

Or you could implement the IRetryAnalyzer
http://seleniumworks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/re-run-failed-tests-automatically.html

Comment: IRetryAnalyzer does not seem to be working if i try to run the same set of tests multiple times in different threads/same threads. `<suite name="SuiteParallel" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
 <test name="Name1">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.poc.test.videotesting.ParallelTest" >
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>

 <test name="Name2">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.poc.test.videotesting.ParallelTest" >
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 ` Where i have 3 failed tests in ParallelTest class.